# Send Email Notification On List Item Change - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to put some logic in SharePoint's List Workflow which I expect to send an email notification to certain users in case of any item change in the list (removed, added a new one). Could you please suggest which condition is more relevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be able to use 'Wait for Event in List Item' action in the SharePoint Designer.  Have a look at this link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj650894.aspx.  Although, I agree with Damein that easier option would be to add status field.

Comment: Custom code an option?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually I am trying to find option to trigger the workflow if item delete as well. But I will play with the method as well! Thanks!

Comment: @TaranGoel no, custom code it not an option I guess :)

Comment: Use SharePoint Alert, as Roland has suggested. Alert trigger mails on deletion also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer, you can create a simple workflow in that list:

1. Open the list in SharePoint Designer, click "List Workflow" in the top left.
2. Add a Condition, "Modified by a specific person", select the user.
3. Add a Action, "Send a Email".
4. In workflow setting, click both "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed and created"

Comment: for some reason it does't work :(

Comment: I have tested again selecting just one user(myself) and it worked, however when I select Modified by: everyone it does't.. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to send an email when an item potentially gets deleted a work flow will not run in every case.

A way around this (OOB) is to use the Alert Me feature.

Click on library/list/Page Ribbon Tab and then select Alert Me and enter the details of the alert as you want them.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it by creating workflow in share point 2013,I shared some basic steps to for creating the workflows.
In the explanation below I'm using SharePoint 2013  but it's absolutely the same in SP2010 or/and on premises, and even in SP2007 the process is very similar.

1) You will need SharePoint Designer installed on your computer.

**For Creating workflow:**

2) Open SharePoint designer

3) Open your site

4) Go to Workflows

5) Click 'List Workflow' on ribbon and select your list

6) Add 'Send email' action

The following block will be added to your workflow:

7) Configure 'Send email' action to use assigned to field for determining          recipient emails
 Also define the body block for the letter. You can use different lookups there,   for example inserting values from the item or item URL or whatever.

8) Now go to 'Workflow Settings'

9) Setup workflow to start whenever item is added or created

10) Publish

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer has an Action called Send an Email.  Workflows can be triggered when a new item is created or changed, but there is no workflow trigger to handle when an item is deleted.

Your easiest option might be to use a status field (such as Open, Closed, Cancelled). When the status is changed, then you can use the Action - Send an email.

Comment: Its a good idea, thanks for that. I will play a little bit with the method above, as it seems to be working one. If no, I will stick to the one you suggested. Thanks!